# Access django runserver from external

Tags: python, django, linux

I setup local server `python manage.py runserver`,then confirmed it works successfully

`wget http://127.0.0.1:8000`

And setup iptables, but can not connect yet.

I checked net setting around and this is `netstat -nap`

Other port 22,25,993,995 etc.... is accessed from external, but 8000 is not possible,

I guess it is because only `8000` has this parameter `127.0.0.1:8000`

Where can I set?

```
$sudo netstat -nap
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1413/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1887/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21651/python        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1788/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1788/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1887/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1788/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:24622               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1466/vsftpd         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1788/dovecot
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify ip as 0.0.0.0 if you want to be it available from your network

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

From the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver):

> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from
>   other machines on your network. To make your development server
>   viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address
>   (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).